# Vuetify styles not applied when styles inside scoped

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

> I am usig Vue.js in this i am applied inspect  v-data-table claSS
>   BASED I gave styles but not applying.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.v-toolbar__title {
  color: indigo;
}
v-data-table-header{
  background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use `::v-deep` to change `scoped` styles

Try

```
::v-deep .v-data-table-header{
  background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

Read more about deep selectors here - https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Comment: <style lang="scss" scoped>
.v-toolbar__title {
  color: indigo;
}
::v-deep v-data-table-header{
  background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
</style>

Comment: `v-data-table-header` is the component name ?

Comment: class name i used vuetify v-data-table

Comment: You cannot apply css to `v-data-table-header` as there is no such html element - Inspect your rendered component in browser, pick the class which will affect the changes try changing it in browser then pick that class and use after deep

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: can u give me your mail please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198574/discussion-between-satyam-pathak-and-lavaraju).

Comment: i need some doubts ! just now i search about you! you are good at this front end if you are okay will u give me